# Testing a Mvc controller that gets data from an API endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am working on a Web project that gets data from an API endpoint. The API layer sits on top of Service Layer and Repository Layer at the bottom. I have written unit testing for the Service and API Layers. I am using Moq framework to mock dependencies.
Now i want to test the MVC controller. I am using a Request Manager class which is derived from HttpClient to get data from the API endpoints. So how do i test this controller. I have written a unit test but the test is getting data directly  from my Database.

```
 public class UserController : Controller
{
    private RequestManager requestManager = new RequestManager();
    // GET: User
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<UserViewModel> allUsers = await requestManager.GetUsers();

        if(allUsers == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "No Users Found");
        }

        return View(allUsers);
    }
}

public class UserControllerTest
{
    public UserController controller;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void InIt()
    {
        controller = new UserController();
    }
    [Test]
    public async Task TestIndex()
    {
        var view = await controller.Index() as ActionResult;
        Assert.That(view is ViewResult);
        Assert.That(view.Model is List<UserViewModel>);
    }
}
```

Comment: abstract away tight coupling and expose dependencies so that they can be mocked/replaced, allowing for greater flexibility during unit test. You're going to have to consider a refactor to improve the testability of your code. Either that or think about using a custom message handler in your httpclient derived manager class

Comment: yeah looks like i have to inject IRequestManager interface to my controller and mock it. How will a custom message handler help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decouple controller and manager. Extract interface from `RequestManager` and inject it into controller. That should not be a problem, Ioc container can do that for you.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private RequestManager _requestManager;

    public UserController(IRequestManager requestManager)
    {
        _requestManager = requestManager;
    }

    // GET: User
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<UserViewModel> allUsers = await _requestManager.GetUsers();

        if(allUsers == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "No Users Found");
        }

        return View(allUsers);
    }
}
```

Then in your unit tests you can mock IRequestManager.

```
public class UserControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestIndex()
    {
        //arrange
        Mock<IRequestManager> requestManager = new Mock<IRequestManager>();
        //setup what you want here...
        UserController sut = new UserController(requestManager.Object);//suggest to use AutoMoqer for this.

        //act
        var view = await sut.Index() as ActionResult;

        //assert
        Assert.That(view is ViewResult);
        Assert.That(view.Model is List<UserViewModel>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private RequestManager requestManager = new RequestManager();
    Mock<RequestManager> mockRepository = new Mock<RequestManager>();
    Mock<UserViewModel> mockUserViewModel = new Mock<UserViewModel>();
    ViewResult viewResult;

    // GET: User
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<UserViewModel> allUsers = await requestManager.GetUsers();

        if(allUsers == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "No Users Found");
        }

        return View(allUsers);
    }
}

public class UserControllerTest
{
    public UserController controller;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void InIt()
    {
        controller = new UserController();
    }
    [Test]
    public async Task TestIndexWhenAllUsersNULL()
    {
        var view = await controller.Index() as ActionResult;
        List<mockUserViewModel> listofusermodel =  new List<mockUserViewModel>();
        //add some dummy data in your List so it will not getting data directly from your Database 
        mockRepository.Setup(x => requestManager.GetUsers()).Returns(listofusermodel);
        Assert.That(view is ViewResult);
        Assert.That(view.Model is List<mockUserViewModel>);
    }
}
```